# Query Stucks Until It Reaches Execution Timeout If I Set Multiple Default Relation To Load Each Query In Laravel (8.54)

Tags: php, laravel

My web app has some static data with some relationships, and instead of fetching them one by one by multiple API requests, I want to make one, collect all data from different models and return. This part is done by the following api route code:

```php
Route::get('base-data', function() {
    return collect(config('consts.base_data'))->mapWithKeys(function($name) {
        $class = "\App\Models\\" . Str::studly(Str::singular($name));
        return [$name => $class::get()];
    });
});

// const.base_data is an array like  ['degrees', 'labels', ...]
```

To load the relations, I added default queries to the models like so:

```
class Degree extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['child', 'parent']; // this blocks the query.

    public function child()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Degree::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Degree::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

If I remove 'child' or 'parent' from the array everything works. Furthermore, if I have another relation in another model, that is also blocking the query. So, basically, I can fetch data from 7 models but I can only load one relation in total.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or it's a bug or design choice, but seems weird.

Any idea about this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do your relationships map out? Are there any cycles?

Comment: Parent and child create a relation in the same table. Maybe that creates a cycle. I don't know. I also tried two different modals and separate relations, and faced the same issue. BTW, I can fetch data in controller if I use ```Degree::with(['parent', 'child'])->get()```

Comment: Just to keep in mind how this would work. When you load a `Degree` Laravel will then do an additional two queries one to get parents and one to get children. When these queries are done then then Laravel does another four queries to get parents and children of the newly acquired parents and children (separately) and will keep happening until no more new parents and children are loaded. By contrast `Degree:with([ 'parents' ,'children'])->get()` will only get the immediate parents and children of `Degree` therefore will only need 3 queries total instead of potentially infinite

Comment: I though ```$with = []``` and ```->with([])``` work the same way, but I don't know. Thanks. I used ->with and no problem.